# How to create XML file with Swift and Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to create XML file with array data like

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><appname>Skype</appname><appname>Word</appname>"

var appname:[String]=["Skype","Word","Excell"]
let post = String(format: "<?xmlversion='1.0'encoding='UTF-8'?>\n\t<" appname=\"%@\" />\n</?xmlversion='1.0'encoding='UTF-8'?>", appname)
```

How to create XML? And how to send this XML to webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code to build your Xml document

```
var appnames: [String] = [ "Skype", "Word", "Excell" ]
var post = "<?xmlversion='1.0'encoding='UTF-8'?><appnames>"

for appname in appnames
{
    let app_node: String = "<appname>\(appname)</appname>"
    post.append(app_node)
}

post.append("</appnames>")
```

Or if you prefer you can change for iterator with...

```
appnames.forEach({ post.append("<appname>\($0)</appname>") })
```

About sending this Xml document to a web service take a look at [URLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequest) Foundation class

Answer (score 0):

```
let appname=["Skype","Word","Excell"]
var post = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
for stringItem in appname{
    post.append("<appname>\(stringItem)</appname>")
}
print(post)
```

Comment: it's the same code of the accepted answer. my answer and adolfo's  answer was posted at the same time.